# readfile downloads an empty file and wrong file type

Tags: php, jquery, csv

I am using the code below to download a csv file from a button click.

**JS**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#CSV", function () {

    var csv_value = $('#result').table2CSV({
        delivery: 'value'
    });
    console.log(csv_value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "csv.php",
        data: {
            csv: csv_value
        },
        success: function (html) {
             window.location.href = "download.php";
        }
    });

});
```

**csv.php**:

```
require_once ("session_start.php");
if (isset ( $_POST ['csv'] )) {
$file = $_POST['csv'];
$_SESSION ['csvf'] = $file; 
} else {
    echo "No CSV Data";
}
```

**download.php:**

```
session_start();
    $file =$_SESSION['csvf'];
    $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
    header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    header ( "Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".csv" );
    readfile($filename);
    exit ();
```

When I execute the function, the file downloaded is `download.php` despite the correct headers being passed (confirmed via console), the file is also empty. Also when I use `print()` it prints the `CSV` data so I know the file isn't empty but it also generates a `.php` file and prints all the contents inside including the headers. How do I fix this issue?

**Edit**

I tried brute forcing the download using the following code in `.htaccess` to no avail.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:csv)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

The result is still a `download.php` file.

Comment: Tip: stop the session before `readfile()`.

Comment: `header ( "Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".csv" );` is missing `Content-disposition` value `attachment;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me using `print()` instead of `readfile()`

```
session_start ();
$file = $_SESSION ['csvf'];
$_table = $_SESSION['table']; //table Name
$filename =$_table."_".date ( "Y-m-d_H-i", time () ).".csv";  
header ( "Content-type: text/csv" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename );
header ( 'Expires: 0' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
header ( 'Pragma: public' );
header ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ( $file ) );
print ($file) ;
exit ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<your file name>".
```

And you have 2 Content-disposition headers (the first one will be overwritten).

Comment: I just tried using this as the header but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply postfix the script location with the filename you want:

```
success: function (html) {
     window.location.href = "download.php/something.csv";
}
```

It will still run `download.php` but the browser will only see the final part of the URL and treat the download as you would expect.

With this in place you can get rid of your `.htaccess` hack as well and reduces the php code to:

```
session_start();
$file =$_SESSION['csvf'];
session_write_close();
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score -2):

I THINK IT HAPPENS AS YOU ARE TRYING TO DOWNLOAD TWO COPIES OF THE SAME FILE THEY WILL CANCEL EACH OTHER OUT

Comment: What file are you talking about ?